# I need to disable a button when there is no any content in my DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms

Here is what I'm trying to do: In there I put a remove button to remove some content in my "DataGridView". When I remove all content I want to disable my remove button automatically. I had tried to do it but it didn't work.

```
 private void btnRemoveImage_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     int selectrow = dataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex;
     dataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(selectrow);
     picbShowUserImage.Image = null;

     int curentrow = 0;
     int rowcount = dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1;

     while(curentrow<rowcount)
     {
         dataGridView1.Rows[curentrow].Cells[0].Value = curentrow + 1;
         curentrow = curentrow + 1;
     }

     if (dataGridView1.Rows[curentrow].Cells[0].Value == null ) 
     {
         btnRemoveImage.Enabled = false;
     }
     else
     {
         btnRemoveImage.Enabled = true;
     }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you try to compare rowcount == 0 instead another values?

Comment: Do you mean like that...                                                                                                                     if (dataGridView1.Rows.Count == 0)
            {
                btnRemove.Enabled = false;
            }
            else
            {
                btnRemove.Enabled = true;
            }

Answer (score 1):

After removing the row, you can simply:

```
btnRemoveImage.Enabled = dataGridView1.Rows.Count != 0;
```

Comment: Where i have to put this code bro... (Still I'm a bigger in programming  )

Comment: After you remove the image (first 3 lines of the method), and remove the remaining lines.